# Nodejs / Express / second router doesn't work

Tags: node.js, express

this code works for my home page

```
router.get('/', async function(req, res, next){
    await default_context('accueil', "Accueil", req.session).then(async (context)=>{
        
        res.render('base/html', context)
    })
})
```

When I want to add a second Router :

```
var another_router = express.Router()
another_router.get('/database', (req, res) =>{
        var posts = []
        console.log("another router")
        res.render('base/html', posts)
})
```

it produces a 404 error

**EDIT**
it produces an error when trying to access with /database in the URL

Comment: why do you put everywhere `async / await` but at the end still using `.then()`

Comment: Which request produces a 404 error as response?

Comment: @bill.gates I have received this code. Is this wrong ?

Comment: @fransua well, it might work, but thats not the way how to write async / await code. If somebody experienced sees this code, he will notice that the programmer who wrote this code has no idea how his code actually works

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want another router?

If all you want is another route then just do `router.get('/database', ...)`

Comment: Yes. Actually I got confused with the mixed async / then syntax used.